# Convert domain name to its URL format for URL parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, dns, urlopen

In my Python script regarding URL html.text parsing, the input to my application is fixed i.e the domain name.

However I need to store and process that domain name into its URL format.
I feel it is not advisable to simply prepend 'https://' to the domain name for the purpose.

As seen below, URL pasring fails because it is receives a domain format not a URL.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import requests

url = 'xyz.com' # it is a domain name. But requires it to be in URL format to perform further parsing.

# Option 1
html=urlopen(url).read()

# Option 2
resp = requests.get(url)
html = resp.text

# Error encountered: Invalid URL.
```

What is a good way to convert a domain name to its URL format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find out whether `"http://"+url` or `"https://"+url` is working, you could just check both:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError

url = 'yourpage.com'
try:
  html=urlopen("https://"+url).read()
except URLError:
  html=urlopen("http://"+url).read()
```